# Does HBase Remove extra cell-versions from the HFiles during Major Compaction?

Tags: hbase

I was wondering when does HBase remove the extra cell-versions from the HFile.

Let's say I have a cell that has 10 versions, but I have configured the column family to store only 1 version.

Does HBase remove the unnecessary cell-versions during Major-Compaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/schema.versions.html)

> Excess versions are removed during major compactions. The number of
>   max versions may need to be increased or decreased depending on
>   application needs.